# is it possible to working with complex file without save it on disk?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a task about working with file in java,user will push your file to api endpoint, i will unzip it, then modify it(ex: add some file, change some file), then return it to user.
This is my strategy:

1. Get .zip file (save it on disk)
2. Unzip it (save it on disk)
3. Get some .zip file on S3 (save it on disk)
4. Unzip s3 file to user upload file (save it on disk)
5. zip user upload file again (save it on disk)
6. return it to user
7. Clean up file on disk

This is my code

```
public Object deliveryApp(MultipartFile file, String s3KeyName, String fileNameTemporary) {
        try {

            //Save fileUpload to disk (.zip file)
            OutputStream osFileUpload = new FileOutputStream("filesDelivery/upload/" + fileNameTemporary);
            osFileUpload.write(file.getBytes());

            //Unzip fileUpload
            ZipFile zipFileUpload = new ZipFile("filesDelivery/upload/" + fileNameTemporary);
            List<FileHeader> fileHeaders = zipFileUpload.getFileHeaders();


            //If .zip file have mutiple root folder -> return error
            String rootFolderOfZipFile = fileHeaders.get(0).getFileName();
            boolean isOneRootFolderInsideZipFile = true;

            for (FileHeader fileHeader : fileHeaders) {
                if (!fileHeader.getFileName().startsWith(rootFolderOfZipFile)) {
                    isOneRootFolderInsideZipFile = false;
                }
            }

            if (!isOneRootFolderInsideZipFile) return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("have mutiple root folder inside .zip file");


            //change root folder to avoid same app name of user
            try {
                zipFileUpload.getFileHeader(fileHeaders.get(0).getFileName());
                zipFileUpload.renameFile(fileHeaders.get(0).getFileName(), fileNameTemporary);
            } catch (ZipException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            //Extract file to upload-extraction
            zipFileUpload.extractAll("filesDelivery/upload-extraction");

            //Get s3 object
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(s3KeyName)
                    .build();
            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3Client.getObjectAsBytes(getObjectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            //Save s3 object to disk (.zip file)
            File fileFromS3 = new File("filesDelivery/s3/" + s3KeyName);
            OutputStream osS3 = new FileOutputStream(fileFromS3);
            osS3.write(data);
            osS3.close();

            //Unzip s3 object to fileUpload of user
            ZipFile zipFiles3 = new ZipFile("filesDelivery/s3/" + s3KeyName);
            zipFiles3.extractAll("filesDelivery/upload-extraction/" + fileNameTemporary);

            //zip file response
            new ZipFile("filesDelivery/response/" + fileNameTemporary).addFolder(
                    new File("filesDelivery/upload-extraction/" + fileNameTemporary));

            File fileResponse = new File("filesDelivery/response/" + fileNameTemporary);
            //return
            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(fileResponse));
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .body(resource);
        } catch (AwsServiceException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

It work well for small request , but when i use the for loop to send over 100 or 1000 request, it not work well, some request get status 500 with some error

This is my code to send request to server

```
  const array =  [...Array(100).keys()]

    
     Promise.all<any>(array.map(async item => {
        formData.set("fileNameTemporary",fileInput.value.name + "__" + Date.now() + "__" + uuidv4());
       
        const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8080/delivery",
      formData,
      {
        responseType: "blob",
      }
    );
    return response.data
    
    })).then(data =>{
        console.log({data})
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log({err})
    })
```

This is some error

```
net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: Could not fill buffer
```

```
java.io.EOFException: null
```

Is seem mess and some people recommend do not save file on disk, is it true?
If it true, are there any solution ?

**THANKS FOR ALL**

Comment: Sure, you can do it all in memory, assuming the data is not too big.

Comment: Doing the job in memory (or a RAM Disk) will likely help performance, but you seem to have functional problem.  Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: @AndrewL sorry but can you explain your comment for me ? My english is not well , i dont know what is stack trace.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788